# to find a complex valued function with a property

Tags: complex-analysis

We need to Find a non constant map $f:\mathbb{C}^3\to \mathbb{C}$ such that for any three distinct complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and any automorphism $\phi$  of $\mathbb{C}$, we have
$f(z_1,z_2,z_3)= f(\phi(z_1),\phi(z_2),\phi(z_3))$

Thank you for help and discussion.

Comment: By automorphism do you mean *field automorphism*? And, I guess $f$ should not be constant..

Comment: @Berci  No every automorphism from $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ has the form $az+b, a\neq 0$,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(z_1,z_2,z_3)=\frac{z_1-z_2}{z_3-z_2}$ will definitely work. Take $\phi(z)=az+b,a\neq 0$